# Connect to SIP server from React Application for audio and video video communication

Tags: reactjs, websocket, webrtc, sip, voip

I'm new to the world of VoIP. I've built a client side app in Reactjs that needs to connect with a SIP server to make and receive calls. Any help on how to connect to the SIP server and how to steam audio and video.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**react-native-jssip** should offer the JavaScript SIP extension:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jssip

Then you need to setup a SIP server with websocket/webrtc support, like Asterisk, FreeSwitch or Kamailio. For the latest, instructions for a sample deployment are available at:

- https://github.com/havfo/WEBRTC-to-SIP